# Trying to refresh opened instances of same page on any browser

Tags: reactjs

Trying to refresh opened instances of same page on any browser, but the code I am trying is only refreshing the current tab. I need to refresh all the same pages.

```
setInterval(
            () => {
                this.CheckFileStatus()
            },
            20000
        );
```

````
CheckFileStatus() {
        if (this.state.canImport === false) {
            const data = {
                "query": "query{fileStatus{status}}"
            };
            API.getItems(data).then(items => {
                if (items !== null && items.fileStatus.status === true) {
                     this.openImportStatusMessagePopUp("some msg");
                }
                else {
                    if (global.successMsg !== '') {
                        this.props.alert.success(global.successMsg);
                        window.location.reload();
                        global.successMsg = '';
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: I don't think you can do this with react. What is the feature requirement?

Comment: Lets say I have opened same page in multiple tabs and when my method which is getting called in every 20 secs refreshing the current tab I need to refresh all the opened tabs so that user need to refresh this manually. I am refreshing page in certain case

Comment: What you can do is every tab according to their passing of 20 seconds would refresh themselves. And just instead of using `window.location.reload()` use `window.location.reload(true);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you can do is every tab according to their passing of 20 seconds would refresh themselves (which is actually you're doing). And just instead of using `window.location.reload()` use `window.location.reload(true);`

Refer https://webplatform.github.io/docs/apis/location/reload/

Comment: Yeah by passing true in reload it is refreshing all the tabs of same page.. thanks you saved my day